# AdMob показался и пропал

Tags: android, admob, реклама

Не работает adMob, пляски с бубном не работают тоже.
В коде ошибок нет!

```
` MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        }
    });
    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-00000000000");
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);`

 mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
            Toast.makeText(MainList.this, "реклама есть", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
            Toast.makeText(MainList.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i("admob", "onAdFailedToLoad");
            Log.i("admob", "error code " + Integer.toString(errorCode));
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
            // covers the screen.
            Toast.makeText(MainList.this, "AdOpen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            Toast.makeText(MainList.this, "left app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            Toast.makeText(MainList.this, "are close", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Code to be executed when the user is about to return
            // to the app after tapping on an ad.
        }
    });

  implementation 'com.r0adkll:slidableactivity:2.0.6'
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.2'
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0-rc01"
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:18.0.0'

implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.1.0'
```

Постоянна ошибка 3. Иногда реклама появляется, но это очень редко, прям очень. И с какой периодичностью, я тоже не могу понять. Жду до 20 минут со включенным экраном и нет рекламы. Потом включаю опять через какое то время и она тут как тут. Стоит закрыть активность и рекламы опять нет.

Comment: Ваше рекламное место просто могут не выкупать из-за малого количества пользователей приложения или неудобного формата(размера) баннера. Это нормальное поведение рекламных сетей.

Comment: А почему тогда в других приложениях работает, которые тоже нигде нет кроме моего устройства.

Answer (score 1):

У вас всё работает, раз реклама иногда показывается. Никто не может вам гарантировать, что вы получите рекламу на каждый запрос оной. У вас может или сеть отвалиться или не найдутся собственно баннеры/видео для показа.

Слабое заполнение приложения рекламой обычно проходит само собой с течением времени и ростом кол-ва пользователей приложения.

Comment: Я тоже так бы и подумал и не парился бы больше. Но есть одно НО, я этот же банер ставил в другое свое приложение, которе тоже никто не видел. Все работает. А в этом приложении нет. И постоянная ошибка 3 в логах.

Comment: По поводу размещения баннера, да на разных страницах ставил, и одинаково.

Comment: Меня единственный момент еще смущает, не может ли повлиять на работу рекламы большое количество методов. Студия пишет, что у меня их больше 80к и требует multidex,  но решил поднять версию до 21 и перестала ругаться.

Comment: @АндрейМостовенко, никто не знает как гугл определяет каким приложениям выдавать много рекламы а каким мало. Т.е. наличие рекламы в одном не гарантироует наличия в другом. Код тут не при чём. Multidex тут тоже не при чём. Если без него собирать под старые (до 5 андроида) телефоны то приложение или не скомпилится или будет при старте падать. Раз у вас уже минимум 5 - то можете об этом просто забыть.

Comment: Ну Вы меня хоть успокоили, а то уже все перерыл. И коды свои с ног на голову и обратно! Вообщем спасибо ))